# Backbone save does not send undefined attributes

Tags: backbone.js

I have the following code :

```
     this.myModel.save(this.patchAttributes, {
        //Ignored if saving new record; will send a POST
        patch: true,
        success: function() {
               success();
            }
        },
        error: function() {
                error();
        }
    });
```

If my patchAttributes has an entry like `fieldName:undefined`, I cannot see it in the request headers of the PATCH request.

Comment: That's exactly as it should be. Since the property is undefined, there is no value to send.

Comment: @StephenThomas can you please send me a backbone documentation link where this is implied? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

That's because Backbone is JSON.stringifying the data before sending it. The JSON spec does not allow the `undefined` token. Therefore any properties that are `undefined` will be omitted from the JSON string.

```
JSON.stringify({ foo: undefined });
// The output is "{}"
```

Instead of `undefined` you should use `null` which *is* part of the JSON spec:

```
JSON.stringify({ foo: null });
// The output is "{"foo":null}"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the correct behaviour, take a look at Backbone source code (https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1357). And btw, I don't think it is stated explicitly in any of Backbone documentations. It is more like common knowledge when dealing with JSON

If you want to keep those "undefined" variables, you need to set them to, say, null by using `defaults` http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults